# Newly Opened Tab kills Function Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < documentsCount; i++) {
    var e = checkBoxes[i];
    if (e.checked) {
        var documentType = documents[i].value;
        if ("ConcreteType_1" == documentType) {
            makeAction();
        } else {
            if (attachmentCount > 0) {
                downloadDoc();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The downloadDoc() function opens an iframe for each file (that has attachemnts and is not of 'ConcreteType_1' type) and the makeAction() function opens a new tab to preview the file source. If I check several files with attachments, everything is fine - several download boxes are raised, but if there is at least one file of 'ConcreteType_1' type among files with attachments, a new tab opens and no download boxes are raised...

If somebody knows how to deal with it, please share.

Comment: I think you need to show the code for makeAction()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disturbing you. The problem was local. There was a script that cleared all the checked boxes after a new tab had opened.